# xidel: wrong order of results on hacker news

Tags: shell, web-scraping, xpath, xidel, hacker-news-api

To scrape [hacker news](https://news.ycombinator.com), I use:

```
xidel -e '//span[@class="titleline"]/a/@href|//span[@class="titleline"]' https://news.ycombinator.com/newest
```

But the output in not in the expected order, the URL come after the text, so it's very difficult to parse.

Does I miss something to have the good order?

I have:

```
There Is No Such Thing as a Microservice (youtube.com)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXCLLsCGY0s
```

I expect:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXCLLsCGY0s
There Is No Such Thing as a Microservice (youtube.com)
```

Or even better

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXCLLsCGY0s There Is No Such Thing as a Microservice (youtube.com)
```

Comment: Why not simply use their [API](https://github.com/HackerNews/API)?

Comment: I don't like GAFAM solutions like firebase

Comment: Parsing is sequential so nodes will be returned on document order not in xpath order. What is the expected output of `//span[@class="titleline"]`?.  Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see ["Using / on sequences rather than on sets"](https://github.com/benibela/xidel/wiki/Caveats#using--on-sequences-rather-than-on-sets) on why this is happening and why you should be using the XPath 3 mapping operator `!` in this case:

```
$ xidel -s "https://news.ycombinator.com/newest" -e '
  //span[@class="titleline"]/a ! (@href,.)
'
```

(also please specify input first)

For a simple string-concatenation this isn't necessary:

```
-e '//span[@class="titleline"]/a/join((@href,.))'
-e '//span[@class="titleline"]/a/concat(@href," ",.)'
-e '//span[@class="titleline"]/a/x"{@href} {.}"'
```

(Bonus) Output to JSON:

```
$ xidel -s "https://news.ycombinator.com/newest" -e '
  array{
    //span[@class="titleline"]/a/{
      "title":.,
      "url":@href
    }
  }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Nodes are returned in document order not in XPath order so additional parsing is needed. With `xmllint` and `awk`

```
xmllint --html --recover --xpath '//span[@class="titleline"]/a/@href|//span[@class="titleline"]/a/text()' tmp.html 2>/dev/null|\
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\n? href="; FS="\n"}{ print $1, $2}' | tr -d '"'
```

Result

```
https://github.com/thesephist/ink Ink: Minimal, functional programming language inspired by modern JavaScript, Go
https://controlleddigitallending.org/whitepaper/ A White Paper on Controlled Digital Lending of Library Books
item?id=35471687 Ask HN: Connect Guitar to Tesla?
```

Note: Xpath in the answer does not need `awk`since href comes before `a/text()` in document order as OP expected. Added for reference on how to change ouput order.

Comment: Yeah, same idea to parte innerText of link. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Wonder how `xidel` handles this xpath `//span[@class="titleline"]`. Seems to return text content instead of the node as is.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better way:

```
$ xidel -e '//span[@class="titleline"]/a/@href|//span[@class="titleline"]/a/text()' https://news.ycombinator.com/newest
```